# how to add a search field in graghql/django

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I am working on this project: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor
I added a column to the product model by adding:

```
account_user = models.ForeignKey(
    Account_User,
    related_name="products",
    on_delete= settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
 )
```

However, after I run "npm run build-schema" and then type

```
query
{
  products(first: 10) {
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        name
        description
        slug
        account_user_id
      }
    }
  }
```

Graghql says ""message": "Cannot query field "account_user_id" on type "Product".",".

Do I miss any step? Do I need to modify the query to add this field? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a **DjangoObjectType** for the `Account_User` model?

Comment: Possibly not. How do I add one? All the code is here: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor if you want to have a look.

Comment: refer the doc, you will find out